# How to Generate a Value that is Unique from the Values of Another Table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, distinct-values

I am trying to generate a value for a column in table 1, but I want it to be distinct from all other values of a certain column in *table 2*. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name-MySQL

Comment: There's no builtin that will do this for you. You'd need to query *"table 2"* to find out if a particular value exists in that table; there's some tricks you could do to "guess" a value that doesn't exist, but the specifics are going to depend on the datatype of *"a column"*. There is no guarantee that this particular value won't later exist in *"table 2"*. (The specification is a bit unusual, an odd use case.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Hmm…Ok. It's a number, if it makes it any better or worse. But this is a little problematic, if there is really no way to do this…thank you though.

Comment: You have to clarify. Do you want ther new value to not exist in the other table now? Or to also never be allowed in the other table, once you insert it in this one?

Comment: @ypercube Not in the other table either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An insert using a select may work - Use which ever aggregate function, or custom function is most appropriate, I am using MAX to get MAX ID of an integer column.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, desc)
SELECT MAX(id)+1, 'Hello World!' FROM table2
```

If the field your inserting to is string based you can just insert a UUID

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (UUID(), 'Hello World')
```

Comment: `MAX(id)` is a value that exists in `table2`. They want the opposite. A value that isn't there.